# window.close() doesn't work on Firefox, any work around?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to close a window using window.close() but this works on IE only but not on Firefox. Has anyone encountered this one and any work around?

Thanks...

Comment: by the way this page is not opened by script. window.open();

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did your script open the window? Firefox 2 and later do not allow scripts to close windows that they did not open.

You could *try* this [trick](http://www.yournewdesigner.com/css-experiments/javascript-window-close-firefox.html), but I have no idea whether it will work. I live on the side of the population that believes users should be in control of their browser windows, not applications (despite the fact you may have a good reason for this).

Comment: Hi pax, it will only work in IE but not on Firefox and Chrome. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and used [this](http://systembash.com/content/close-firefox-window/) recently. Hope it helps.

Comment: it is the same as what pax linked. works only on IE not of FF and Chrome.

Comment: Did you try the trick from one of the comments, near the end in that link?

Answer (score 2):

This is a security feature added in FF. You can see that this has been deliberately not allowed from Mozilla site docs.

This method is only allowed to be called for windows that were opened by a script using the window.open method.

Answer (score 2):

`window.close();` worked for me (FF 31.5.0).  However, in order for me to get it to work I had to change the advanced settings:

about:config -> dom.allow_scripts_to_close_windows = true;

Comment: This solution is useful when the window is opened by an extension like Greasemonkey or Tampermonkey.