# Why is window.Close() not working in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox

Why javascript: `window.Close()` is not working in Firefox, Is there any solution?

What are the parameters in `window.Close()`?

Comment: Could you be more specific? Which Firefox version are you using and where are you executing this command? In the address bar? You can [read more about `window.close()` at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.close). Also note that JavaScript is case sensitive, so it should be `close`, not `Close` and you can only close windows you opened with JavaScript.

Comment: There is/was a workaround for closing windows that you haven't opened with javascript, but I don't know if it is still working :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [window.close() doesn't work on Firefox, any work around?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754374/window-close-doesnt-work-on-firefox-any-work-around)

Answer (score 4):

In firefox you can't close a window that is not opened by javascript(pop-up). window.close() will not work.

Answer (score 1):

Probably because it is `window.close()` - with a lower-case `c`. JavaScript is a case-sensitive language, `close` and `Close` are not the same thing.