# how to close the browser window

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [window.close() doesn’t work on Firefox, any work around?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754374/window-close-doesnt-work-on-firefox-any-work-around)

I need to close the current browser window when click on the button using jquery. I tried many ways, but they do not work for all browsers: My code is:

```
$('#btnCloseBrowser').click(function () {
//                close();
//                this.close();
//                window.parent.close();
//                window.close();
//                self.cose();

            window.setTimeout("window.close()", 1000);
    });
});
```

// close(); // this.close(); // window.parent.close(); // window.close(); // self.cose();

This works for IE but not work for FIREFOX,CHROME

Comment: Did you do any [research](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2512687)?

Comment: This has been asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/760422/how-can-i-close-a-window-with-javascript-on-mozilla-firefox-3

Answer (score 0):

Look at [How to close current tab in a browser window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076299/how-to-close-current-tab-in-a-browser-window?rq=1)

Note that only windows opened using JavaScript can be closed using `window.close()` otherwise typically newer browsers don't allow windows to be closed arbitrarily.

Comment: -1 This answer is already in the comments posted above