# window.close() workaround for firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [window.close() doesn’t work on Firefox, any work around?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754374/window-close-doesnt-work-on-firefox-any-work-around)

I'm using firefox 17.0.1 and the method `window.close()` is not working with me, here is the code `<button onclick="window.close()">Close<button>`
It works on chrome, how to close the current window using js in firefox ??

Comment: Are you calling this code from inside a popup that you have previously opened with `window.open`?

Comment: You cannnot close windows that were *not* opened by JS itself.

Comment: Wouldn't that be bad UI design anyway?  Phoowwwwffff: "your browser just closed"